# Head control of 6 month old baby

Tags: infant, development

My baby girl has completed 5 months yesterday. She doesn't have good head control. And I am worried. When I lift her in my arms, she does not control her head and leans backward from waist. Plz to reply for this:-)

Comment: Babies are different, and they grow on their pace. I would just recommend if you're worried you can try speaking to the pediatrician. I know of one incident where the baby couldn't support herself until 8 month's but the Dr's helped and she's now healthy and very big. So just speak to the pediatrician

Answer (score 3):

There are no rules concerning babies. Each individual is special and has his own rules.

My twins wouldn't sit unsupported until they were 9 mo, after that they crawled and walked fast.

You can give her additional time and it is not a bad idea to consult your pediatrician.